# Decode Sql Query

Tags: sql, pivot

There are lot of records in a table. Querying time increases a lot. so i need to take rows as columns using decode method. eg:

```
Empid   Date         type  value
1       01-Jan-2018  Att    1.0
2       01-Jan-2018  Att    0.5
3       01-Jan-2018  Lev    1.0
1       02-Jan-2018  Att    0.5
1       03-Jan-2018  Att    1.0
2       03-Jan-2018  Att    1.0
```

I need output as follows

```
Empid   01-Jan-2018   02-Jan-2018   03-Jan-2018
1        1              0.5           1
2        0.5                          1
3        1
```

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Why do you think this will be any faster?

Comment: This is a very vague question. _"Querying time increases a lot"_ Using what query? When did it start to increase? _"i need to take rows as columns using decode method"_ What is "decode method"? Why do you need it?

Comment: This is very database backend specific. The code that will work for SQL Server might not work for Oracle or my SQL and vice versa. We cannot answer your issue without knowing the database backend.

Comment: Backend is oracle. Eg. table contains around 1 lakh records in a month.while taking in report, date should be shown in column wise. 1 emp will have 31 records in a month. for around 4000 emp. it will reach in lakhs.